# String back from Bundle

Tags: android, string, bundle

From 1st ACTIVITY

```
Intent IntentButton = new Intent();
IntentButton.setClass(this, PaliActivity2.class);
IntentButton.putExtra("EditText123", EditText1.getText().toString());
startActivity(IntentButton);
```

2nd ACTIVITY

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                     
setContentView(R.layout.nextscreen);
Bundle BundleFrom1 = getIntent().getExtras();
```

How to get the String back from Bundle received from Activity1???

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
String s = BundleFrom1.getString("EditText123");
```

please name the variables with lower chase beginning

Comment: please tick the right answer. 
`TextView textview = (Textview) findViewbyId(R.id.textview1);
textview.setText(s);`